# Running gensim failing after install in anaconda

Tags: gensim

I have downloaded anaconda and have also successfully downloaded gensim.

I am trying to run gensim but not making much progress. I am running jupyter.

When I try the following command in jupyter:

```
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec
```

I get the following:

```
At line:1 char:1
+ from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec
+ ~~~~
The 'from' keyword is not supported in this version of the language.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ReservedKeywordNotAllowed
```

What am I missing?

Comment: This doesn't look like a Python error. Are you running this code in Powershell?

Comment: Yes.. am I meant to be running it in powershell? Have tried powershell and jupyter..
Struggling to find tutorials on how to actually run gensim

Comment: I got it working! Thanks santitizedUser. Your question was a trigger! Running it in pythonLab now and it's outputting as expected :)